# Need some explanation about package in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am having a little problem understanding the following command:

```
package ifneeded HelloWorld 1.0 [list source [file join $dir helloworld.tcl]]
```

in the pkgIndex.tcl,
I understand that when the pkgIndex.tcl is sourced and for example, we package require HelloWorld 1.0 , the helloworld.tcl will be sourced. I dont understand the list command...

Answer (score 7):

The `package ifneeded` command is used to register (or query) how to make a package actually become present in a Tcl interpreter. This is done by evaluating a script, which is the argument generated with `list` in your example. Let's deconstruct it.

```
   package ifneeded HelloWorld 1.0 [list source [file join $dir helloworld.tcl]]
   ---------------- ========== --- =============================================
    command name     package   ver           how to make it present,
                      name                    result of [list ...]
```

So far, so good. Now, a little aside: the `list` command is not just used for making lists, but it also makes *guaranteed-substitution-free* commands. That is, its result is a scrip that consists of an invocation of the command with its arguments, exactly as they were when they went into the `list` command.

This means that we're producing a script that is `source somefilename`, where `somefilename` is the result of the `file join`. In other words, you're getting *almost* the same thing as:

```
package ifneeded HelloWorld 1.0 "source $dir/helloworld.tcl"
```

*Except* that there is no assumption that the filename separator is `/` (that's formally a feature of the OS, not of Tcl, and `file join` knows about the difference) *and* it is safe if `$dir` happens to contain a space or other metacharacters (rather more common than you might hope).

What is `$dir`? Well, it's a special feature of `pkgIndex.tcl` scripts that they are (normally) evaluated in a context that sets the `dir` variable to the absolute name of the directory that contains the `pkgIndex.tcl` script. (You mustn't make assumptions about the current directory at this point; that belongs to the user of the main Tcl program, not to the package author.) This makes it enormously easier to relocate a package, as you can place all its component files relative to the one script and just move the whole lot in one chunk.

Comment: The other advantage of using `list` is that Tcl's hidden type system allows its results to be evaluated much more efficiently. The difference here is virtually unmeasurable though, as the I/O involved in `source` will dominate by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

The **package ifneeded** command [expects](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10006) the following inputs:

```
package ifneeded package version ?script?
```

You can see that in your case, the **package** is HelloWorld, and the **version** is 1.0. Finally, the **script** is [list source [file join $dir helloworld.tcl]]. The reason **list** is used is that the script parameter expects a list.

Answer (score 1):

The `package ifneeded` command expects a script as its last argument.  A script is expected (in a common sense) to be well-formed, that is, to be parsable by the Tcl parser.

In this case of a rather standard `pkgIndex.tcl`, the thing to ensure is: no matter what the "dir" variable contains at the time the code from that `pkgIndex.tcl` is processed, the script should be constructed in such a way, that later the Tcl parser sees in it the `source` command with *exactly one argument* — no matter if `$dir` expanded to contain whitespace or funky characters like `{` etc.

Enter the `list` command.  Here, it's used to construct a list of two elements: the string "source" and a string containing a file name (to serve as the sole argument to that `source` command).  Now, when that list is interpreted as a script (a string), Tcl ensures that string representation contains all the needed quoting to remove any ambiguity about whitespace etc.
This ensures when the parser later interprets our constructed script, the `source` command in it will receive exactly one argument.

You can read much more of better written information on using `list` to prevent quoting issues [here](http://beedub.com/book/3rd/Eval.pdf).